# Function of a matrix - intuition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis

In my lecture notes there is a topic on functions of matrices. Let $A\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, and let $f$ be a "nice" function (the lecture notes didn't specify what "nice" means). We define $f(A)$ as in the following Wikipedia article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_function

My question is, why do we choose to define $f(A)$ in such  a way? What do we get from it?

Comment: "Such a way" ? What do you call "such a way" ? The Wikipedia article just says that "a matrix function is a function which maps a matrix to another matrix"...

Comment: You can define functions from any domain to any other codomain however you like.  You can have inputs of matrices mapping to outputs of other matrices.  You can have inputs of baby dolls mapping to names of said baby dolls.  You can have inputs of jabberwockies mapping to vorpal swords.  What do we get from it?  Whatever we want.

Comment: @R Are you specifically referring to the [extension of a scalar function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_function#Extending_scalar_function_to_matrix_functions) $f: \Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ into a matrix function?

Comment: Are you interested by explanations about this formula: $\displaystyle f(A)={\frac {1}{2\pi i}}\oint _{C}\!{f(z)(zI-A)^{-1}}\,\mathrm {d} z$ ?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you refer to the extension of a function $f:\Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ so that $f(A)$ can be interpreted, as I mention in my comments.

One motivation comes from linear differential equations. Suppose that we are interested in solving the differential equation $\frac{dx}{dt} = Ax$ and initial condition $x(0) = x_0$ ($x$ is a vector and $A$ is a matrix).  In the scalar (or "$1 \times 1$") case, solving this is straightforward: we arrive at the solution
$$
x(t) = e^{At} \cdot x_0.
$$
This solution works because $\frac d{dt}e^{At} = A e^{At}$.

Now, if we could define the function $e^X$ for a matrix input $X$ in a "natural" way, then we could do the same thing for our more complicated system. In particular, if $e^X$ is defined in such a way that $e^0 = I$ and $\frac d{dt} e^{At} = Ae^{At}$, then it follows that $x(t) = e^{At}x_0$ satisfies
$$
\frac d{dt} x(t) = \frac{d}{dt} e^{At}x_0 = Ae^{At}x_0 = Ax(t), \quad x(0) = e^{0}x_0 = x_0,
$$
which means that we have a solution to our system. That brings us to exactly the situation in your lecture notes: we have a "nice" function $f(x) = e^x$, and it would be useful if we could make sense of $f(X)$ for a matrix $X$.

---

Note that this $f$ is very nice in that it has a power series that converges for all inputs. However, it is often useful to apply this analysis to functions that are less nice such as $g(x) = \log(x)$. In some applications, it is also useful consider $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ in this way.

In general, an approach to extending such functions is referred to as a [functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_calculus).